# Trying to creat a csv file, but its all double space

Tags: python

when I write \r\n to the csv file im trying to create, it puts in 2 new lines, so its like i did \r\n \r\n.  The sample code crests a spreed sheet like this

test

test

test

Outline Report

```
o.open()
bit.loadBuysSells()
o.addJustString("ted \r\n test \r\n test \r\n test \r\n")
o.addTitle("Outline Report")

def addJustString(self,add):
    # add a string to a line of the spreed sheet
    self.f.write(add)
```

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` in the string. Python will convert them to `\r\n` if necessary on Windows (assuming you've opened the file in text mode).

Answer (score 1):

you might want to replace all \r\n with just \n.

One way to do that is: `theString.replace("\r\n","\n")`

in your case:

```
o.addJustString("ted \r\n test \r\n test \r\n test \r\n".replace("\r\n","\n")
```

However i would consider using the python csv package:

- Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
- Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

To end lines in the correct way for any given operating system use os.linesep:

```
import os
o.open()
o.addJustString("ted" + os.linesep + "test" + os.linesep + "test" + os.linesep + "test" + os.linesep)
```

Or better yet make your helper function handle that for you:

```
import os
o.open()
o.addJustString("ted")
o.addJustString("test")
o.addJustString("test")
o.addJustString("test")

def addJustString(self, add):
    """add a string to a line of the csv file"""
    self.f.write(add + os.linesep)
```

os.linesep will be \n on linux and \r\n on windows